# Server wont recv the second time

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a client and server, the server is setup this way:

```
int listenS = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in s = { 0 };
s.sin_family = AF_INET;
s.sin_port = htons(PORT);
s.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IP_ADDR);
bind(listenS, (struct sockaddr*)&s, sizeof(s));
listen(listenS, QUEUE_LEN);

struct sockaddr_in clientIn;
int clientInSize = sizeof clientIn;
while (1)
{
    int newfd = accept(listenS, (struct sockaddr*)&clientIn, (socklen_t*)&clientInSize);
    //......
```

(*There are tests I just removed them to make the code more readable)*

The client is just:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), nrecv;
struct sockaddr_in s = { 0 };
s.sin_family = AF_INET;
s.sin_port = htons(PORT);
s.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IP_ADDR);
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&s, sizeof(s)) < 0)
{ //......
```

I get a connection, and everything is working great, the server `recv` a message the first time I send it from the client, but when I try to `send` another message to the server the server wont block the `recv` call and get nothing (*returning the buffer size, not 0*)

Here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define PORT 0x0da2
#define IP_ADDR 0x7f000001
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int send_all(int socket, void* buffer, size_t length)
{
    char *ptr = (char*)buffer;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        int i = send(socket, ptr, length, 0);
        if (i < 1) return -1;
        ptr += i;
        length -= i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if ((strcmp(argv[1], "list-files") != 0) &&
            (strcmp(argv[1], "upload-file") != 0) &&
            (strcmp(argv[1], "download-file") != 0) &&
            (strcmp(argv[1], "search") != 0))
            {
                perror("The arguments are incorrect.");
            }

        int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), nrecv;
        struct sockaddr_in s = { 0 };
        s.sin_family = AF_INET;
        s.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        s.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IP_ADDR);
        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&s, sizeof(s)) < 0)
        {
            perror("connect");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Successfully connected.\n");

        char sendBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int lenOfArgv = strlen(argv[1]);
        int sendBufferIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0;
            i < lenOfArgv && sendBufferIndex < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
            i++, sendBufferIndex++)
        {
            sendBuffer[sendBufferIndex] = argv[1][i];
        }

        if (argc == 3)
        {
            sendBuffer[sendBufferIndex++] = ' ';
            int lenOfArgv = strlen(argv[2]);
            for (int i = 0;
                i < lenOfArgv && sendBufferIndex < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
                i++, sendBufferIndex++)
            {
                sendBuffer[sendBufferIndex] = argv[2][i];
            }
        }

        sendBuffer[sendBufferIndex] = 0;

        // + 1 for terminating null
        if (send_all(sock, sendBuffer, strlen(sendBuffer) + 1) < 0)
        {
            perror("send buffer to server failed");
            return 1;
        }

        if(strcmp(argv[1], "download-file") == 0)
        {
            char sizeBuffer[256];
            recv(sock, sizeBuffer, 256, 0);
            int fileSize = atoi(sizeBuffer);

            if(fileSize > 0)
            {
                FILE* recievedFile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
                if(recievedFile != NULL)
                {
                    int remainData = fileSize;
                    size_t len;
                    char fileBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                    while(((len = recv(sock, fileBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0 && (remainData > 0)))
                    {
                        fwrite(fileBuffer, sizeof(char), len, recievedFile);
                        remainData -= len;
                        printf("Received %d bytes, %d is left..\n", len, remainData);
                    }
                    fclose(recievedFile);
                    printf("File downloaded!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    perror("Failed to download file\n");
                }
            }
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "upload-file") == 0)
        {
            char filePath[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            sprintf(filePath, "%s", argv[2]);
            int fd = open(filePath, O_RDONLY);
            int downloadFailed = 0;
            if (fd != -1)
            {
                struct stat file_stat;
                if(fstat(fd, &file_stat) >= 0)
                {
                    char fileSize[256];
                    sprintf(fileSize, "%d", (int)file_stat.st_size);
                    int len = send(sock, fileSize, sizeof(fileSize), 0);
                    if(len >= 0)
                    {
                        int remainData = file_stat.st_size;
                        off_t offset = 0;
                        int sent_bytes = 0;
                        while(((sent_bytes = sendfile(sock, fd, &offset, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) && (remainData > 0))
                        {
                            remainData -= sent_bytes;
                            printf("sent %d bytes, %d is left...\n", sent_bytes, remainData);
                        }
                    }else {downloadFailed = 1;}
                }else {downloadFailed = 1;}
            }else {downloadFailed = 1;}

            if(downloadFailed == 1)
            {
                perror("Failed to download file!\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            char someBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            // nrecv is the number of bytes that we recieved
            if ((nrecv = recv(sock, someBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) < 0)
            {
                perror("recv");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("%s\n", someBuffer);
        }

        close(sock);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        perror("The arguments are incorrect.");
    }
}
```

here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>

#define PORT 0x0da2 // 3490
#define IP_ADDR 0x7f000001 // 127.0.0.1
#define QUEUE_LEN 20
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int send_all(int socket, void* buffer, int length)
{
    char *ptr = (char*)buffer;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        int i = send(socket, ptr, length, 0);
        if (i < 1) return -1;
        ptr += i;
        length -= i;
    }
    return 0;
}

void list_dir()
{
    DIR * directory;
    struct dirent* dir;
    directory = opendir(".");
    if (directory)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name); // /home/text.txt, text.txt
            // get filesize (in bytes0 with dir->d_name
        }
    }
}

void list_files(char* buffer, int withBytes = 0)
{
    DIR* d;
    struct dirent* dir;
    d = opendir("data");
    int bufferIndex = 0;
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        char tempFilename[256] = "data/";
        int tempIndex = 5;
        char* scan = dir->d_name;
        while(*scan)
        {
            tempFilename[tempIndex++] = *scan;
            buffer[bufferIndex++] = *scan++;
        }
        tempFilename[tempIndex] = 0;
        struct stat st = {0};
        stat(tempFilename, &st);
        int fileSize = st.st_size;

        if(withBytes == 1)
        {
            // Adding file size to the buffer
            bufferIndex += sprintf(&buffer[bufferIndex], " %d bytes", fileSize);
        }

        buffer[bufferIndex++] = '\n';
    }
    buffer[bufferIndex] = 0;
    closedir(d);
}

int main(void)
{
    int listenS = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listenS < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in s = { 0 };
    s.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    s.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IP_ADDR);
    if (bind(listenS, (struct sockaddr*)&s, sizeof(s)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }
    if (listen(listenS, QUEUE_LEN) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        return 1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in clientIn;
    int clientInSize = sizeof clientIn;

    struct stat st = {0};
    if(stat("data", &st) == -1)
    {
        mkdir("data", 0700);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        int newfd = accept(listenS, (struct sockaddr*)&clientIn, (socklen_t*)&clientInSize);
        if (newfd < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            return 1;
        }
        int pid = fork(); // creating new thread 
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            close(listenS); // duplicate=> thats why we need to close the socket

            char someBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int nrecv;
            if ((nrecv = recv(newfd, someBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) < 0)
            {
                perror("recv");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Message recieved: %s\n", someBuffer);

            // Here we read the command the argument and split them
            // into seperate variables
            char command[256];
            char argument[256];
            int commandHasBeenSet = 0;
            char* token = strtok(someBuffer, " ");
            while(token != NULL)
            {
                if(commandHasBeenSet == 0)
                {
                    strcpy(command, token);
                    commandHasBeenSet = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(argument, token);   
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }

            if (strcmp(command, "list-files") == 0)
            {
                char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                list_files(buffer, 1);

                if (send_all(newfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1) < 0)
                {
                    perror("send buffer to client failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                printf("Sent a message to a client!\n");
            }
            else if (strcmp(command, "upload-file") == 0)
            {
                printf("Uploading file %s\n", argument);
                char sizeBuffer[256];
                recv(newfd, sizeBuffer, 256, 0);
                int fileSize = atoi(sizeBuffer); 

                if(fileSize > 0)
                {
                    char filePath[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                    sprintf(filePath, "data/%s", argument);
                    printf("Downloading to %s", filePath);
                    FILE* recievedFile = fopen(filePath, "w");
                    if(recievedFile != NULL)
                    {
                        int remainData = fileSize;
                        size_t len;
                        char fileBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                        while(((len = recv(newfd, fileBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0 && (remainData > 0)))
                        {
                            fwrite(fileBuffer, sizeof(char), len, recievedFile);
                            remainData -= len;
                            printf("Received %d bytes, %d is left..\n", len, remainData);
                        }
                        fclose(recievedFile);
                        printf("File downloaded!\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        perror("Failed to download file\n");
                    }
                }else
                {
                    perror("Failed to get file size for download\n");
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(command, "download-file") == 0)
            {
                char filePath[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                sprintf(filePath, "data/%s", argument);
                int fd = open(filePath, O_RDONLY);
                int downloadFailed = 0;
                if (fd != -1)
                {
                    struct stat file_stat;
                    if(fstat(fd, &file_stat) >= 0)
                    {
                        char fileSize[256];
                        sprintf(fileSize, "%d", (int)file_stat.st_size);
                        int len = send(newfd, fileSize, sizeof(fileSize), 0);
                        if(len >= 0)
                        {
                            int remainData = file_stat.st_size;
                            off_t offset = 0;
                            int sent_bytes = 0;
                            while(((sent_bytes = sendfile(newfd, fd, &offset, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) && (remainData > 0))
                            {
                                remainData -= sent_bytes;
                                printf("Server sent %d bytes, %d is left...\n", sent_bytes, remainData);
                            }

                        }else {downloadFailed = 1;}
                    }else {downloadFailed = 1;}
                }else {downloadFailed = 1;}

                if(downloadFailed == 1)
                {
                    perror("Failed to download file!\n");
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(command, "search") == 0)
            {
                char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                char result[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int resultIndex = 0;
                list_files(buffer);

                result[0] = 0;

                char tempBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                strcpy(tempBuffer, buffer);
                token = strtok(tempBuffer, "\n");
                while(token != NULL)
                {
                    char* scanToken = token;
                    char* scanArgument = argument;
                    int found = 1;
                    while(*scanToken && *scanArgument)
                    {
                        if(*scanToken++ != *scanArgument++)
                        {
                            found = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if(found == 1)
                    {
                        if(resultIndex > 0)
                        {
                            result[resultIndex++] = ' ';
                        }
                        strcpy(&result[resultIndex], token);
                        resultIndex += strlen(token);
                        result[resultIndex] = 0;
                    }

                    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
                }

                if (send_all(newfd, result, strlen(result) + 1) < 0)
                {
                    perror("send buffer to client failed");
                    return 1;
                }
                printf("Sent a message to a client!\n");
            }

            close(newfd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            close(newfd);
    }


    close(listenS);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run the server, and then run the client with commands like:

```
./client list-files
./client download-file test.txt
```

it will work fine, the client will receive messages from the server and vice versa.

The problem occurs when I try to run:

```
./client upload-file test.txt
```

which is essentially the same as `download-file` command, just copied and pasted to the server from the client (same logic, should work the same), except it doesn't.

*Specifically the program fail at line 175 of the server (`recv(newfd, sizeBuffer, 256, 0);`), it gets 0 instead of the value the client is sending it.*

Any idea what I am missing?

(I tried searching online but didn't find anything)

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a streaming protocol. There is no message boundaries, and server's `recv`s do not correspond to client's `send`s.

The client sends the command with

```
    send_all(sock, sendBuffer, strlen(sendBuffer) + 1)
```

OTOH, the server tries to receive it with

```
    nrecv = recv(newfd, someBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0))
```

`recv` does not care whether the stream contains a `'\0'` or not. It blindly waits for `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` bytes to come in. Some (valuable) data sent by the client is in `someBuffer` just past the command, but ignored by the server.

The server must parse the reply more diligently. For that you likely need a more elaborated protocol (e.g. prefix each string with its length).

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming the stream socket will preserve your message boundaries. It will not. So, you're sending something like:

```
upload-file filename\0
NNN\0\0\0...\0   [256 bytes containing filesize]
<content of filename>
```

So probably the first `recv` you do on the server side (of `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` bytes) is receiving not just the command string and the filename, but also the file size block and the entire file content. That is, you've already received it all and it's sitting in `someBuffer`. Your initial command string is null-terminated so you would not be aware of the rest of it unless you check `nrecv`. Hence, your next `recv` call gets end-of-file because the client is finished and has closed its end of the connection.

To send defined records over TCP, you need to know exactly how many bytes are expected at each point, and receive exactly those (or be prepared to parse the received data). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47440054/1076479